# How to I use env variables in npm scripts

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I'm building and signing an Electron app and I'm trying to contain my certificate location and sha pass to an environment variable.

Is this how I pass the env variables to an npm script?

```
"electron-pack-win": "CSC_LINK=process.env.REACT_APP_CSC_LINK CSC_KEY_PASSWORD=process.env.REACT_APP_CSC_KEY_PASSWORD build --win
```

Worth mentioning that I'm using create-react-app

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me. If you have `process.env. REACT_APP_CSC_LINK` why do you even need another environment variable `CSC_LINK ` which will essentially be `process.env.CSC_LINK `

Comment: @AnandUndavia well CSC_LINK takes a link to a certificate file, which I store in REACT_APP_CSC_LINK. Same for CSC_KEY_PASSWORD

My logic was that storing those values in the env variable will simplify the process for other dev who would be new to it. They'd just create the env file and populate the fields from our docs

Comment: You mean to say `CSC_LINK` is environment variable which is being used by some other framework/library?

Comment: @AnandUndavia that's right! 

CSC_LINK and CSC_KEY_PASSWORD are used by the Electron build script to sign the installer with a certificate (the cert is encrypted hence the password).

Comment: Alright! Added the answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments,

Your `.env` already contains `REACT_APP_CSC_LINK`.
All you need to do is define a variable in the `.env`
For example,

```
REACT_APP_CSC_LINK=some_value
CSC_LINK=some_value
```

`Electron` will be able to access the environment variables using `process.env.CSC_LINK`

Answer (score 1):

The ambient environment variables will be passed through to the script/program being run by `npm`, so if you set something in your shell - on Windows,

```
set CSC_KEY_PASSWORD=hello
```

or in Bash shells,

```
export CSC_KEY_PASSWORD=hello
```

, they will be available to the program being run.

Only if you want to override some values would you use the syntax you mentioned (or [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) to be cross-platform compatible).

Comment: I was hoping to use my syntax to abstract the variable setting away from package.json. A new dev would just need to create a .env file and set the values there.

If I set the variables outside of the package.json script do I still need to pass them to the build script?